# how to protect my file

Tags: vb.net, csv, visual-studio-2005

After generating a file, I don't want to allow anyone to open it.

1. How do I protect it, by using a password?
2. Is there any better way?
3. How do I do it programmatically?

Comment: How would you like to use this file after it's "protected"? Should your own program be able to open it?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to protect and who are you protecting it from?

If you're going to put your  credit card number in it and ship it off to the Russian Mob, then you'd need rather strong encryption.  If you're trying to obfuscate the contents from standard users, a simple ASCII shift would be OK.

.Net has encryption routines built in.  The Code Project (nice site, by the way) has a good article those encryption routines [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/SimpleEncryption.aspx).

If you're the administrator of the machine, and those you are trying to protect the contents from are not administrators, then simply change the permissions of the file.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is just a text file. It doesn't have any protection of its own.

You could encrypt it, or zip it up (with a password), for example. But then you will need to decrypt it/unzip it before you could use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

1) You could Encrypt the file.  Then even if people can open the file they won't be able to read it.

2) Zip it up and password protect it.  See [dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) from codeplex.

Comment: please share me how to do the first option - Encrypt the file.

Comment: A quick search on stackoverflow or google will give you lots of ways of doing this.  I suggest you have a look and then post another question once you have tried if you get stuck.